# Пробую сделать таблицу умножения

Tags: php

Пробую сделать таблицу умножения. Должно быть как на картинке. Не могу понять в чем проблема

[image: это вывод моего кода][image: сгенерировать на PHP]
мой код

```
`<?php
echo '<table border="1">';
for ($tr=1; $tr <= 10 ; $tr++ ) {
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($td=1; $td <= 10; $td++) {
        echo '<td>'."$tr x $td = " . $tr * $td.'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

`

Comment: А в чём сейчас, собственно, проблема?))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не как на картинке, видимо :D

Comment: результат вывода получается что каждый пример в отдельной ячейке 1*2 = 1 в ячейке и т.д. А необходимо чтоб умножение на 1 (отдельная ячейка) и т.д.

Comment: надеюсь понятно объяснил)))))

Comment: вы прежде чем код писать, идею сформируйте в голове у себя как это вооще делать. Поименуйте переменные, а то бессмыслица какая то. `$cols, $rows=10` а на картинке видим 5 и 2. Есть у вас цифры от 1 до 10, вот их и используйте. чтобы таблицу умножения составить надо двойным циклом по ним пройтись.  В верхнем цикле вы выводите ячейки. После пятой ячейки генерите новую строку. Во вложенном цикле вы выводите в ячейку непосредственно значения умножений.

Comment: добавил результат вывода своего кода...(первая картинка) я просто новичок в этом(( И спасибо за обратную связь)))

Comment: Не нужно повторно превращать заголовок в базар

Comment: Не превращаю в базар. На сайте первый раз. Случайно удалил заголовок. Попросил помощи...мда...

Answer (score 0):

```
//Есть у вас цифры от 1 до 10
$nums = range(1,10);

// первая строка
echo "<tr>";

//начинаем выводить ячейки
foreach($nums as $x){
    echo "<td>"; 

    // выводим столбец умножения  
    foreach($nums as $y){
       echo "$x x $y = " . $x*$y . "<br/>"
    }
    echo "</td>"

    //после 5й начинаем новую строку
    if($x == 5)  echo "</tr><tr>"
} 
echo "</tr>"
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 0):

Несколько советов:

1. Всегда старайтесь максимально отделять код РНР от кода HTML при таком подходе в случае необходимости намного проще вносить правки
2. Старайтесь разбивать код на функции. Каждая функция выполняет отдельное действие. В таком случае значительно легче поддерживать код. Вы не будете плодить дублирование кода.
3. Переменные называть нужно так чтобы по названию понимать для чего она. Тогда вам через некоторое время будет значительно проще разобратся в вашем коде.
4. Перед написанием кода в голове или на листочке сформулируйте алгоритм что за чем должно идти.

Алгоритм (исходя из нужной картинки):

- Создаем таблицу
- В таблицу добавляем ряд в котором будет 5-ть столбцов
- Добавляем столбец  куда помещаем умножение на 1 (повторяем даное действие для 2, 3, 4, 5)
- Добавляем в таблицу второй ряд в котором будет 5-ть столбцов
- Добавляем столбец куда помещаем умножение на 6 (повторяем даное действие для 7, 8, 9, 10)

Сам код:

```
//Считаем произведение
function multiplication($multiplier_1, $multiplier_2){
    return $multiplier_1 ." x ". $multiplier_2 ." = ". $multiplier_1*$multiplier_2;
}

//Считаем произведение для некого числа
function multiplication_by($multiplier){
    for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){
        $multiplication_column .= multiplication($multiplier, $i) ."</br>";
    }
    return $multiplication_column;
}

//Формируем столбцы для диапазона произведений
function table_columns($from, $to){
    for($i=$from; $i<=$to; $i++){
        $columns .= "<td>". multiplication_by($i) ."</td>";
    }
    return $columns;
}

//Формируем ряд для диапазона столбцов произведений
function table_row($columns_from, $columns_to){
    $row .= "<tr>". table_columns($columns_from, $columns_to) ."</tr>";
    return $row;
}

//Формируем ряды для диапазона столбцов произведений
function table_rows($amount_rows=2, $amount_columns=5){
    $from = 1;
    $to = $amount_columns;
    for($i=1; $i<=$amount_rows; $i++){
        $rows .= "<tr>". table_row($from, $to) ."</tr>";
        $from = $to + 1;
        $to += $amount_columns;
    }
    return $rows;
}

//Выводим таблицу
echo '<table border="1">'. table_rows() .'</table>';
```

Передавая в `table_rows()` параметры можно формировать таблицу умножения с разным количеством рядов и столбцов. Например для 3 рядов по 5-ти столбцов будет `table_rows(3, 5)` - в результате получим таблицу умножения от 1 до 15-ти.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!!! И огромное спасибо за Ваши советы!!